# IE6 Not caching my images

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, xhtml, internet-explorer-6, browser-cache

I uploaded my web application already in my Production Tomcat Web Server.
I am trying to test it already and it works fine on FF/IE7/IE8 but I am having a problem
on display on IE6.

I notice in the status bar that IE6 seems to be downloading the images every now and then.
Even though I did not click anything, it still downloads the images.

I am using a menu that uses images and it does not display well on IE6.  Problem is that 60% of my targeted user
runs on this browser.

I am beginning to think that this is a browser cache problem.  In all my JSP, I place below meta tag in all the head section.
I did this because my apps relies heavily on Ajax and I need the latest copy of my web resource.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
</head>
```

Could this be the culprit and is there any workaround for this? How can I force IE6 to cache those images?  Thanks.

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for but kindly advise if I miss anything.

This is an example of an Image being downloaded.  I forgot to mention that this apps runs only on our local intranet web site.

@Pekka, Is this what you are looking for?

```
Response Headers
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Etag    W/"1957-1275442082000"
Date    Mon, 18 Oct 2010 11:37:00 GMT

Request Headers
Host    atpapps03:9090
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept  image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://atpapps03:9090/rts/css/menu.css
Cookie  JSESSIONID=0DD210EE0B2788A7774B10D477734DA9
If-Modified-Since   Wed, 02 Jun 2010 01:28:02 GMT
If-None-Match   W/"1957-1275442082000"
Cache-Control   max-age=0
```

Comment: Please use Firebug to get the response headers of the image resources, especially the caching related ones, and post them here as well

Comment: if 60% of your uses run on IE6 you should have done your development on IE6  (you have now got the face the pain, that you choose to advoid by developing on anther brower)

Comment: @Ian What are you talking about? This is a caching question, not a HTML display issue

Comment: @Ian I develop my apps using firefox alone.  I then check that everything works as expected.  When I tested it with IE6, I encountered lots of browser display issues.  But Thanks to IE6 conditional hacks, I was able to fix them and they all look the same now in FF/IE6/IE7/IE8.  My problem actually is that the images does not load that fast in IE6 and it downloads the images everytime.

Comment: @Pekka, it is still a problem in IE6 that over half of the users have.  So I think the best risk control always comes from developing on the lowest brower that a lot of your users have.

Comment: @Ian I still don't see what you're talking about. He is noticing a non-obvious caching problem in IE6 - what would developing the site using IE6 have changed about that?

Comment: @Pekka  My office network protocol is blocking the uploading of the images in SO. I will upload later when I got home.  I checked on the Firebug Net for the images Request and Response Header.  Any idea where I should check?  Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: 60% IE6 usage? I pity you immensely. Given that stat, I would have turned down the project.

Comment: @Spudley Yup.. Its such a pity but thats how my situation goes and I cannot turned down any project so I will have to make both ends meet to make it work on IE6.. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In all my JSP, I place below meta tag in all the head section. I did this because my apps relies heavily on Ajax and I need the latest copy of my web resource.

There are two problems:

1. The meta tags are ignored by the webbrowser. Put this information in the response header.
2. Even when it wasn't ignored, the meta rules would only apply on the HTML output of the JSP and thus **not** on all linked resources (img, js, css, etc) inside the HTML output. They have each their own rules in their own response header.

Your best bet is using a [`Filter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which adds the [`Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header on a far-future date on static content.

```
private static final long DEFAULT_EXPIRE_TIME = 604800000L; // ..ms = 1 week.

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final long twoWeeksAhead = System.currentTimeMillis() + DEFAULT_EXPIRE_TIME;
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).setDateHeader("Expires", twoWeeksAhead);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Map this filter in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` covering the URL of interest, e.g. `/images/*`.

Comment: Thanks.  YSLOW grade for Expire now is A and I am seeing a considerable Load Time Speed Now in IE6. Thanks thanks!

Comment: On one thing, do you have an idea why only IE6 exhibits this kind of behavior?  Why IE7/IE8/FF is doing fine..

Answer (score 1):

see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583912/clarification-on-usage-of-cache-control-header) on how to control the caching settings for static file types.

Comment: @Pekka I posted above a sample of an image file from a Jquery UI Image.  Is this what you are looking?

Comment: @Mark yup. You need to change the server side settings for caching

Comment: @Pekka.  Thanks.  I will check out on this although I honestly dont have an idea yet on how to do this.  I will ask for advise as I am still a beginner on Spring MVC

Comment: You might have overlooked that his "Cache-Control" header was on the request, not the response. That's because he refreshed this page while doing the network capture. But the general advice is correct-- you need to set a freshness lifetime on this image. See http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf

Comment: @BalusC @Eric (facepalm) of course. I must have been asleep. Cheers, I'll remove that bit

Answer (score -1):

[Pekka is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958484/ie6-not-caching-my-images/3958753#3958753), its likely the caching control.
A way around this would be to load your images from a different subdomain with a different set of cache headers.  If you use a CDN provider, they will set the cache control for you.

IE SUCKS! id test it on IE 7-8-9.  Very few use IE6
if its an intranet app, a quick fix would be Chrome frame, detect it, and if its not installed redirect to a download page.